# В Gulp сборке есть коллекция собственных снипетов, написаны они правильно с точки зрения синтаксиса, но при попытке их вызвать, они не срабатывают

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, scss

В проекте не получается воспользоваться готовыми сниппетами, подскажите, как исправить это

Comment: 1) обновить node, gulp, все плагины 2) я бы не держался руками за конкретный gulpfile.js, он может быть просто с ошибками написан, в интернете их тысячи 3) есть смысл переходить на webpack вместе со всеми. можете запостить пример снипета, который не срабатывает, обычно проблема в папках/доступа к ним

Comment: webpack подходит для решения одних задач, а gulp для решения других. в большинстве случаев подходит gulp

Comment: согласен, для статических приложений лучше gulp, а для динамических (react) лучше webpack (с шаблоном cra). хотя я видел, как на cra и лендинги лепят. поищите на github шаблоны для gulp.